# Wrap an ordered list of nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi I have an xml document which look like that:

```
<a> <!-- Several nodes "a" with the same structure for children -->
    <b>12</b>
    <c>12</c>
    <d>12</d>
    <e>12</e>
    <f>12</f>
    <g>12</g>
</a>
```

I'm trying to obtain the following document using xslt 2.0

```
<a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>12</c>
    <wrap>
        <d>12</d>        
        <e>12</e>
        <f>12</f>
        <g>12</g>
    </wrap>
</a>
```

I started my xsl file with

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And changed it for several cases like replacing a string part, filter some nodes, etc.
But I'm stuck with "selecting four consecutive nodes", any clue on how to achieve the wrapping?

Comment: Can you select the nodes to wrap, specifically? Is it always the same set (d,e,f,g)?

Comment: This is always the same set with the same order (d,e,f,g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can also make use of `for-each-group group-adjacent`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::d | self::e | self::f | self::g)">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
              <wrap>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </wrap>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If all your `a` elements are genuinely exactly the same structure then the simplest would be a brute-force

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="b | c" />
    <wrap>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="d | e | f | g" />
    </wrap>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or if you want to be a bit cleverer

```
    <wrap>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (b | c)" />
    </wrap>
```

If you want to always "wrap" the last four child elements of `a`, then how about

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:variable name="lastFour" select="*[position() &gt; (last() - 4)]" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except $lastFour" />
    <wrap>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$lastFour" />
    </wrap>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: plus one for simplicity -- err, specificity